# laravel check last iteration of foreach loop while using if condition in the foreach loop

Tags: php, laravel

How to find the last item in the foreach loop if Im using @if inside the foreach, I want to find it so I want to remove the dot after the last item, I want these dots to be shown only between items like: hello . Help . 
I know the way using loop-->last, but it doesnt work becuase the @if conditon shows different last item, which means if we have 100 items but when we use if it will show let say the item 1 and 42 and 63 so the last item here is 63 but when use loop->last will show that last item is 100

Here but what I have is like this: Here.

```
@foreach($cuisines as $cuisine)

    @if(($cuisine->id)==($scuitem->cuisine_id))
        {{ $cuisine->title }} •
    @endif 

@endforeach
```

Comment: Need you to use `$end = end($cuisines)` before loop and match with `$end->cuisine_id == $cuisine->id` inside loop

Comment: didnt get what you mean

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use $loop->last :

```
@foreach($cuisines as $cuisine)
       @if(($cuisine->id)==($scuitem->cuisine_id))
          {{ $cuisine->title }} 
         @if(!($loop->last))
            •
         @endif
       @endif 
@endforeach
```

**Edited :**

Now Use this code in Controller and pass `$str` to view

```
$arr = [];
foreach($cuisines as $cuisine){
  if(($cuisine->id)==($scuitem->cuisine_id)){
    $arr[] = $cuisine->title;
  }
}
$str = implode(' • ',$arr);
```

Or if you want to code in view than use as below :

```
@php
  $arr = [];
  foreach($cuisines as $cuisine){
    if(($cuisine->id)==($scuitem->cuisine_id)){
      $arr[] = $cuisine->title;
    }
  }
  $str = implode(' • ',$arr);
@endphp
```

Comment: I know this way but it doesnt work becuase the @if conditon shows different last item, which means if we have 100 items but when we use if it will show let say the item 1 and 42 and 63 so the last item here is 63 but when use loop->last will show that last item is 100, u got what I mean?

Comment: thank you but how to print out the result? I tried to make another loop for $arr by using foreach ($arr as newcouisine) but its the same result

Comment: @AshMalek, than you just need to code {{ $str }} where you want to display result

Answer (score 2):

Laravel actualy has [the `$loop` variable](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/blade#the-loop-variable) with information about the current iteration.

For example `$loop->last` is a boolean indicating if we are on the last iteration.

```
@foreach($cuisines as $cuisine)
    @if(($cuisine->id)==($scuitem->cuisine_id))
        {{ $cuisine->title }}{{ $loop->last ? '' : ' •' }}
    @endif
@endforeach
```

Comment: I know this way but it doesnt work becuase the @if conditon shows different last item, which means if we have 100 items but when we use if it will show let say the item 1 and 42 and 63 so the last item here is 63 but when use loop->last will show that last item is 100, u got what I mean?

Comment: Wouldn't it then be a better idea to move the filtering to the controller? Otherwise you will have too much logic in your views.